# Displaying a fixed number of children in a form using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In a form, I need to display a fixed number of models in the has_many collection whether or not they exist. So for example:

Say there's a game, and there are 10 scores that can be entered. But not all need to entered - you can enter anywhere form 0 to 10. Yet the form still always displays 10 score inputs.

This is how I implemented it:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord
  has_many :scores
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scores

  alias :scores, :original_scores

  def scores
    return original_scores if caller[0] =~ /.*fields_for.*/
    scores_to_display = original_scores # could be anywhere from 0 to 10
    # fill out the array up to 10
    return scores_to_diplay
  end
end
```

This is ugly since I'm essentially overriding the ActiveRecord::Relation object that's supposed to be returned by the has_many - that's why I return original_scores if the caller isn't the form helper, since otherwise this breaks deleting and other association methods. I'm not sure how it can be done cleaner. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could start with an empty array like this:

```
scores = Array.new(11,0)  # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Then fill it with available scores.

This is similar conceptually to using a 'left outer join' in SQL or doing a find on original scores and then `include` the current scores which also uses left outer joins.

Answer (score 0):

First, have Game reject any scores that are blank

```
class Game < ActiveRecord
  has_many :scores
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :scores, :reject_if => :all_blank
end
```

Then, in your controller, build 10 scores to show on the form

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @game = Game.new
    10.times { @game.scores.build }
  end
end
```